# Open a new session in another terminal window without blocking the calling terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I want to run `tmux new-session -s name` from a terminal. The tmux should open in another terminal without blocking the calling terminal's input.

What i tried

```
tmux new-session -s name &   <--- Completely messes up the tmux session
nohup tmux new-session -s name &    <---- Doesn't work too
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Why don't you open a new terminal and then run tmux?

Comment: i want to run this from a bash script. call tmux new session from main bash script. The created tmux will output depending on what the user selects on the main terminal window which has lot of options to select from so the main window should not be blocked and the tmux should be running simultaneously

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities.. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: this is not about configuring unix utilities. im trying to make a bash script. but im stuck at this point.

Comment: Launch a new terminal window as a background process and tell it to run `tmux`.  The terminal command will depend on your system (could be `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` or `sakura` or `xfce4-terminal` or ...) so you'll have to figure that out first.  `ps -efa | grep term` might show you what terminal program you're currently using. Then look at its man page to see how to tell it to run a command.  That's usually `-x <command>`. So you'll end up running something like `xterm -x tmux &`.

Comment: I'm targeting a very large number of users who would be using terminals that i havent even heard of. So this method is also not possible